# How can I create podfile in my terminal if it shows command not found?

Tags: firebase, flutter, podfile

I am adding firebase to my iOS app in flutter.

Problem occurs in the add firebase SDK step. I run the command `pod init` in my terminal but it says `-bash: pod: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `sudo gem install cocoapods` in terminal to install **Cocoapods**. See this [guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started) for more information. Then create podfile with `pod init` command.